# Are there premixed Material Design color combinations I can use for prototyping?

Tags: mobile, color, color-scheme, material-design

I'm looking at [this tool that allows to select material design colors](http://www.sankk.in/material-mixer/) and [this document by Google that describes how to pick material design colors.](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html)

As far as I understand, I pick 3 primary colors and 1 accent color. My question: **are there "premixed" combinations of Material colors I can use for prototyping?**

Comment: Just one copmment: you're not supposed to choose 3 primary colors, but 1 primary color and 2 shades (3 hues). From Material's guide:  "Limit your selection of colors by choosing three hues from the primary palette and one accent color from the secondary palette. "

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for: http://www.materialpalette.com/

You initially pick two colors, and it gives you a palette of colors.

Comment: That is a great tool, BUT it doesn't answer the question--which colors go well together?

Comment: An important question, but not what Alex was asking.

Comment: @ChadSchultz - granted that not the question that Alex was asking as Alan says but you still raise a very important issue.  I have found [http://colorpalettes.net/](http://colorpalettes.net/) to be a really nice visual resource for evaluating which colors work well together.